# Insert an SQL Server Table rows into a Bigquery table in one bloc

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, cfml, google-bigquery

I want to insert all rows of an SQL server Table into a BigQuery Table having the same schema.

The streaming insert row by row is very slow: to insert 1000 rows the execution of the code below took about 10 minutes.

In this code I loop over the first 10 files in a certain folder, and I insert the content of this file in a unique SQL Server Table. Once I looped over the desire files, I loop over the SQL Server table (which contain all rows of all files) and I insert the content row by row in a BigQuery Table.

This operation is very slow. Does someone have a better (faster) solution to insert the content of an SQL server Table into a BigQuery Table automatically (via a code)?

```
<cfsilent>
    <cfinclude template="app_locals.cfm" />
    <cfinclude template="act_BigqueryApiAccess.cfm" />
</cfsilent>

<!--- 1er traitement BQ: Insertion des colis traités --->
 <!--- enregistrement du début du 1er traitement BQ (TShipping)--->
<cfset BigqueryTShipping_StartDate=now()>
<cfset QueryName = "InsertBigqueryLogTShippingStartDate">
<cfinclude template="qry_item.cfm"> 

<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#FileRoot#\_data\_Bigquery\TShipping" listinfo="all" type="file" name="FList" sort="datelastmodified">
<cfset FileList = Valuelist(FList.name)>
<cfoutput><h3>FileList: #FileList#</h3></cfoutput>

<cfif len(trim(FileList))>
    <!--- traiter les 10 derniers fichiers (les MaxNbFile moins récents) --->
    <cfset FileLoop = 1>
    <cfloop list="#FileList#" index="FileName"> 
        <cfset PathFile="#FileRoot#\_data\_Bigquery\TShipping\#FileName#">
        <cfset QueryName = "InsertTShipping">
        <cfinclude template="qry_item.cfm"> 
        <cfset FileLoop = FileLoop+1>
        <cfif FileLoop GT Attributes.MaxNbFile>
            <cfbreak />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>

<!--- instancier un objet de type (class) TableRow --->
<cfobject action="create" type="java" class="com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow" name="row">
<!--- <cfdump var="#row#"> --->

<cfset QueryName = "GetParcels">
<cfinclude template="qry_item.cfm"> 
<cfloop query="GetParcels"> 
    <cfset row.set("Tracking_Date",mid(Tracking_Date,6,19))>
    <cfset row.set("TShipping_ID", TShipping_ID)>
    <cfset row.set("TShipping_Tracking", TShipping_Tracking)>
    <cfset row.set("Shipper_ID", Shipper_ID)>

    <cfset rows.setInsertId(sys.currentTimeMillis())>
    <cfset rows.setJson(row)>

    <cfset rowList.add(rows)>

    <cfset content=rqst.setRows(rowList)>

    <cfset response = bq.tabledata().insertAll(Project_ID,Dataset_ID,Table_ID, content).execute()>  
</cfloop>

<!---vider la table TShipping_BQ--->
<cfset QueryName = "DeleteOldTShipping_BQParcels">
<cfinclude template="qry_item.cfm">

<!--- Suppression des fichiers traités ---> 
<cfif len(trim(FileList))>
    <cfset TShippingFileNb=len(trim(FileList))>
    <cfset FileLoop = 1>
    <cfloop list="#FileList#" index="FileName"> 
        <cfset PathFile="#FileRoot#\_data\_Bigquery\TShipping\#FileName#">
        <cffile action="move" source="#PathFile#" destination="#FileRoot#\_data\_Bigquery\TShippingArchive">
        <!--- <cffile action="delete" file="#PathFile#"> --->
        <cfset FileLoop = FileLoop+1>
        <cfif FileLoop GT Attributes.MaxNbFile>
            <cfbreak />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
<cfelse>
    <cfset TShippingFileNb=0>
</cfif>


<!--- enregistrement du nb de fichiers TShipping traités --->
<cfset QueryName = "InsertBigqueryLogTShippingNb">
<cfinclude template="qry_item.cfm"> 
 <!--- enregistrement de la fin du 1er traitement BQ--->
<cfset BigqueryTShipping_EndDate=now()>
<cfset QueryName = "InsertBigqueryLogTShippingEndDate">
<cfinclude template="qry_item.cfm">
```

Answer (score 3):

## **Wrong Approach**

I think what you are trying to do makes sense, however I think that your row-by-row approach is what is making this so slow. Anything you do row-by-row with SQL (e.g., a cursor or loop) will be slow because you are executing the whole section of query anew for each row. All SQL is optimized to work with large data sets, not single rows.

## **Suggested Approach**

I feel sure that you could establish a connection so the BigQuery server directly and pass it sets of data via [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) or similar approach. Contact the people at BigQuery to help with this.

Do scan through your files to insert the data into your local SQL server. Then you could just do something like:

```
INSERT INTO [BigQueryServer].[database].[schema].[table]
    SELECT * FROM [LocalServer].[database].[schema].[table]
    WHERE [LocalServer].[database].[schema].[table].[added_timestamp] -- or whatever column you use to keep track of records added
        >= '2014-07-01' -- or whatever date
```